# How to tag a git revision and then listing tagged revisions

Tags: git

I want to tag some of my revisions in a git repo and then list the revisions which are tagged.
Please advise, 
thanks

Comment: Did you check the documentation of git tag : http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Basics-Tagging ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git tag <tagname> <commit>` creates a tag pointing to a commit. `git tag` will list all the tags and `git show <tagname>` will give you details about the commit that  points to.  The `show` command works for any [treeish](http://schacon.github.com/gitbook/4_git_treeishes.html).

Also, you should really read the docs. This is a rather simple question you could have gotten the answer to by just skimming the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

`git tag <tag name>` to create a tag, if you want to create a tag for previous revision you can git checkout  and then git tag. More info here: http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-tag.html

To list all the tags do `git tag -l`